# Определить ссылки в тексте и возможность взаимодействия с ней

Tags: python, tkinter

Как определить в tkinter в тексте ссылку? Возможно как-то ее выделить и если возможно, то при нажатии на нее открыть браузер с ней.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import scrolledtext

window = Tk()

txtscroll = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(window, width=20, height=20)
txtscroll.insert(INSERT, 'https://google.com')
txtscroll.config(state='disabled')
txtscroll.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W+NS+E, padx=(5,5), pady=(5,5))

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50327234/adding-link-to-text-in-text-widget-in-tkinter

Comment: @splash58 не совсем то

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно через регулярные выражения искать:

```
import re
import webbrowser
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import scrolledtext


def open_link(event):
    try:
        start, end = event.widget.tag_prevrange("link", "insert")
    except ValueError:
        start, end = "1.0", "1.0"
    link = event.widget.get(start, end)
    webbrowser.open_new_tab(link)


window = Tk()

txtscroll = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(window, width=20, height=20)
txtscroll.insert(INSERT, 'произвольный текст https://google.com произвольный текст '
                         'https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1497622/')
txtscroll.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W + NS + E, padx=(5, 5), pady=(5, 5))

# привязываем регулярное выражение к событию нажатия на ссылку
txtscroll.tag_config("link", foreground="blue", underline=1)
regex = r'\b(https?://[^\s]+)\b'
for match in re.finditer(regex, txtscroll.get("1.0", END)):
    start = txtscroll.index("1.0 + %d chars" % match.start())
    end = txtscroll.index(start + " +%d chars" % len(match.group(0)))
    txtscroll.tag_add("link", start, end)
    txtscroll.tag_bind("link", "<Button-1>", open_link)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: работает, но не совсем. Да ссылку определяет, выделяет и срабатывает открытие браузера, но в нем в поисковую строку вноситься не только ссылка: ```file:///home/odinson/PycharmProjects/MegaParser/site%20https://google.com``` а если `scrolledtext` содержал еще и обычный текст и ссылок было больше, оно все окажется в поисковой строке.

Comment: @krolaper поправил код

Comment: @Игорь_Крещенников ошибка: ```start, end = event.widget.tag_prevrange("link", "insert")
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)```

Comment: @krolaper у меня работает, но добавил обработку

Answer (score 1):

По мотивам вот этого ответа [Python TKinter get clicked tag in text widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33954343/python-tkinter-get-clicked-tag-in-text-widget/33957256#33957256)

```
import re
import webbrowser
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import scrolledtext


def click(event):
    # get the index of the mouse click
    index = event.widget.index("@%s,%s" % (event.x, event.y))

    # get the indices of all "link" tags
    tag_indices = list(event.widget.tag_ranges('link'))

    # iterate them pairwise (start and end index)
    for start, end in zip(tag_indices[0::2], tag_indices[1::2]):
        # check if the tag matches the mouse click index
        if event.widget.compare(start, '<=', index) and event.widget.compare(index, '<', end):
            # take string between tag start and end
            webbrowser.open_new_tab(event.widget.get(start, end))

window = Tk()

txtscroll = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(window, width=20, height=20)
txtscroll.insert(INSERT, 'текст со ссылками')
txtscroll.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W + NS + E, padx=(5, 5), pady=(5, 5))

# привязываем регулярное выражение к событию нажатия на ссылку
txtscroll.tag_config("link", foreground="blue", underline=1)
regex = r'(https?://\S+)'
for match in re.finditer(regex, txtscroll.get("1.0", END)):
    start = txtscroll.index("1.0 + %d chars" % match.start())
    end = txtscroll.index("1.0  + %d chars" % match.end())
    txtscroll.tag_add("link", start, end)
    txtscroll.tag_bind("link", "<Button-1>", click)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: работает отлично